# Counter not available with custom trace

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-performance

I'm using `Firebase Performance Monitoring` plug-in for my projects, in order to track / inspect my code.

I create a `Trace` on the `onPreExecute()` method of custom `AsyncTask` (here I post only the methods where I use `Trace`) :

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    // Start trace which track the analysis of raw data
    Trace trace = FirebasePerformance.getInstance().newTrace(traceTag);
    mTraceMaps.put(traceTag, trace);
    trace.start();
    trace.incrementCounter(counterTag, totalItems);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bundle result) {
    // Stop trace which track the analysis of raw data
    Trace trace = mTraceMaps.get(traceTag);
    if (trace != null) {
        trace.stop();
        mTraceMaps.remove(traceTag);
    }
}
```

Please note that `traceTag` and `counterTag` are constants in my class.

The problem is that I can't see anything on **Firebase console**. I'm expecting an `int` showing me how many raw data I collected.

Am I missing something ? Does my code is correct ?

Comment: You're using `tag` to create the trace, then using a different variable `traceTag` to stop it later.  Maybe they're different.  For an AsyncTask, I wouldn't even both putting traces into a map.  The trace could just be a member variable of the AsyncTask itself, measuring only that instace.

Comment: @DougStevenson my bad, I copied my code on SO without pasting the correct name. I will fix my question.

Comment: @DougStevenson they finally show up: it seems that It only takes patience. By the way, does it takes also some amount of data in order to see the counter on console ?

Comment: I believe it's currently a 12 hour delay.  I'm not sure if there is a volume requirement to get things to show up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that It only takes patience and after 12 hours delay they finally show up.